# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects when using tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

when I try to run code over and over I sometimes randomly get an error

```
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Startup\twitterapi.py", line 54, in <module>
twitterStream.filter(track=["asdfqw"])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 430, in filter
self._start(async)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 346, in _start
 self._run()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 286, in _run
raise exception
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Sometimes the code works fine and sometimes it doesn't. When I rerun it several times It eventually works. What can be the problem? Is it something wrong with my code or with tweepy?
here is my code

```
class listener(StreamListener):
def on_data(self, data):
    tweet = json.loads(data);
    #print json.dumps(tweet, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    #print tweet['text']
    try:
        tweetid = tweet['id_str']
        print tweetid
    except:
        try:
            tweetid = tweet['id']
        except:
            pass
    try:
        userid = tweet['user']['id_str']
    except:
        pass
    try:
        text = tweet['text']
    except:
        pass
    cur.execute(r"INSERT INTO twitterfeeds(tweet_id, user_id,body,status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, '0')",(tweetid, userid, text))
    db.commit()
    #print "pass"
    return True
def on_error(self, status):
    print "Error: " + status
#while True:
#   try:

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["asdfqw"])
#    except:
#       pass
```

Comment: what is line number `286` in your code?

Comment: my code has only 57 lines, the error occurs in tweepy library i guess

Comment: Ohhh sorry..din't see that(my miss). Does my answer address your problem?

Comment: yup it solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

`print "Error: " + status`

with

`print "Error: " + str(status)`